# is there a better way to provide xml documentation for this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, documentation, xml-documentation

I have the following class constructor and I've added some initial xml documentation:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for initializing SecurityApiServiceWrapper
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="apiBaseUrl">The base url to use for SecurityApi calls
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="apiVersion">The version of the SecurityApi to use</param>
        /// <example>
        /// apiBaseUrl of "https://security.mycorp.com" will call SecurityApi in prod
        /// apiVersion of "2" will direct subsequent API calls to /api/v2/...
        /// </example>
        public SecurityApiServiceWrapper(string apiBaseUrl, string apiVersion)
        {
            _apiBaseUrl = apiBaseUrl;
            _apiVersion = apiVersion;
        }
```

It seems like it would be cleaner semantically if I took the each of the line in the  section and nested each line within the corresponding  tag after the main param description.  However, VS intellisense doesn't bring that nested structure up as an option.  Is there a better way to provide parameter examples than what I've configured in the code sample that I've provided above?

Comment: Can you show what you want to do (as well as what you have).  I've read over your description three times and I'm still not following.  For what it's worth, I like to put the summary contents on the same line as the `<summary>` tag.  That way, when you collapse the comments, that description still shows up.

Comment: What about `paramref` ?